# What would be a good algorithm for sorting objects by importance?

Tags: sorting

The algorithm I'm trying to make is one in which you can sort items by how many times and how quickly they've been seen by users. It's in a lot of websites (the sort by relevance feature) for Stack Overflow and it's very widely used. The algorithm I'm trying to make is just a combination of how quickly the users have seen the link, and how many times have they seen a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have all the datas in an array (links and their visit counter) you can sort them with quicksort comparing each link counter. Quicksort is the best sorting algorithm with O(n log n) order.

Here more information about quicksort
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort

Answer (score 1):

There are a TON of different factors that impact relevance, but here are some useful links:

- [Wikipedia on general relevance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relevance_%28information_retrieval%29)
- [relevance in search engines](http://www.xav.com/scripts/search/help/1074.html)